# How to change position of code folding buttons in RMarkdown?

Tags: css, r, r-markdown

Given this example yaml, the code folding buttons render on the right:

```
---
title: "Some Title"
output:
  html_document:
    code_folding: hide
    theme: united
---
```

This does not look appealing to me, I would like them on the left. At the moment, I include this override in the body of the .Rmd document:

````
```{css, echo=FALSE}
/* Move code folding buttons to the left */
div.col-md-12 .pull-right {
  float: left !important
}
```
````

This works but feels a bit dirty. Plus it is hard to predict what mayhem it may cause in combination with some other elements that may happen to be used in future documents.

Is there a "proper" way to customize this in RMarkdown?

Comment: Unfortunately, using css seems the only way and a safer option would be to add a custom class to code fold buttons and then apply css rule for that class instead of redefining the existing class or choosing the selectors more specifically (suppose adding `button` before `div.col-md-12 .pull-right`.

Comment: Nice, that would be a safer option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be no built-in option for setting the position of the code-folding in Rmarkdown and [Quarto](https://quarto.org). If you want to have the code-folding buttons on the left side without using CSS you could use Quarto with an html-document, which is standard on the left side. Here is a reproducible example:

````
---
title: "Some Title"
format:
  html:
    code-fold: true
---

```{r}
print("Hello World!")
```
````

Output:

[image]

---

[Here](https://quarto.org/docs/output-formats/html-code.html) you can find some extra information about Folding Code in Quarto.